# BB Press plugin WordPress error

Tags: wordpress, plugins, bbpress

I have used the BB press plugin in WordPress to create a forum. I have been able to list down the forum topics but when I click on a forum topic then I get the following error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\bbpress\includes\forums\functions.php:1800 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(298): bbp_pre_get_posts_normalize_forum_visibility(Object(WP_Query)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(515): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php(1681): do_action_ref_array('pre_get_posts', Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php(3238): WP_Query->get_posts() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp.php(617): WP_Query->query(Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp.php(735): WP->query_posts() #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php(955): WP->main('') #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(16): wp() #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17): require('C:\\xampp in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\bbpress\includes\forums\functions.php on line 1800
```

I am unable to figure out the rootcause. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cause is incompatibility with PHP7.1, if you revert to PHP7.0 it will work...
There is a bbPress beta which may address the issues but reverting to PHP7.0 would be the more stable solution right now.